# Callbacks Windows.Devices.Geolocator.StatusChanged and PositionChanged

Tags: geolocation, win-universal-app

When I subscribe to a Geolocator.StatusChanged event sink, does Geolocator calls back immediately first event with the current status or I need to get actual status through a Geolocator.LocationState property right after subscription on the callback? 
And the same for PositionChanged - does Geolocator calls back immediately after subscription and when location is available?

Comment: Did you actually just try it? Not sure, but as the events are named *...Changed* they will only get fired when an actual change happens. You can just read the properties at the moment you subscribe, so there is no need to immediately fire the event.

Comment: Yes, I can subscribe and then read current status, but here I can have a race where first thread does - subscribe, get current state, store current state to local member, and second thread (which is used for call back) updates the same local member with value, which comes in the callback. Then I need also use synchronization around (subscribe + get current value + store value) and around (callback with new value + store value).

Comment: So that's a special case and you should add some code to your question. But basically: If you read status first and then subscribe to the event, you are fine.